# Rotation semigroup and identity element.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, semigroup-of-operators

Let $\Gamma =\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$, and $X=C(\Gamma)$. The rotation semigroup $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$, is defined as
$$T(t)f(z)=f(\mathrm{e}^{it}z),\quad f\in X.$$
$Z\in X$, s.t. for all $z\in\Gamma$,  $Z(z)=z$. Then $T(t)Z(z)=Z(\mathrm{e}^{it}z)=\mathrm{e}^{it}z$. Or we can say that any complex number $z=\mathrm{e}^{ix}$ is mapped to $\mathrm{e}^{i(x+t)}$. My question is, does $T(t)$ map $Z$ to itself? As I think, it is only true whenever $t$ is a multiple of $2\pi$.

P.S. I just want to confirm, either I am right or not!

Comment: It's customary to use $1$ as the name for the constant function whose value is unity. Then $T(t)1=1$ for all $t$. A better name for your function might be $Z(z)=z$. Then $T(t)Z=e^{it}Z$, which is equal to $Z$ only when $t$ is a multiple of $2\pi$, as you say.

Comment: Sir I have denoted it by $1$, to make it different from identity operator. as $T(0)=I$.

Comment: your suggestion worth a lot, I'll edit the question! :)

Comment: No need to edit. It's just a note to let you know that your notation is a bit non-standard. Just as $\sin^{2}(x)=\sin(x)\sin(x)$, then $Z^{2}(z)=z^{2}$. This is why the notation is more convenient; otherwise you end up with $1^{2}\ne 1$, which can be confusing.

Comment: Yes Sir, I got it. Thank you!

Comment: So, what do you think Sir? $T(t)$ does not map $Z$ to itself. right?

Comment: You are correct. $T(t)$ does not map $Z$ to itself unless $t$ is a multiple of $2\pi$. However $T(t)$ maps any constant function to itself, regardless of the constant value that the function equals.